# What is the best way to count the number of times a value occurs in an array?

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I have been given an assignment to write a program that reads in a number of assignment marks from a text file into an array, and then counts how many marks there are within particular brackets, i.e. 40-49, 50-59 etc. A value of -1 in the text file means that the assignment was not handed in, and a value of 0 means that the assignment was so bad that it was ungraded.

I could do this easily using a couple of `for` loops, and then using `if` statements to check the values whilst incrementing appropriate integers to count the number of occurences, but in order to get higher marks I need to implement the program in a "better" way. What would be a better, more efficient way to do this? I'm not looking for code right now, just simply "This is what you should do". I've tried to think of different ways to do it, but none of them seem to be better, and I feel as if I'm just trying to make it complicated for the sake of it.

I tried using the 2D array that the values are stored in as a parameter of a function, and then using the function to print out the number of occurences of the particular values, but I couldn't get this to compile as my syntax was wrong for using a 2D array as a parameter, and I'm not too sure about how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are all of the ranges ten numbers long?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a couple for loops? one is enough.

Create an array of size 10 where array[0] is marks between 0-9, array[1] is marks between 10-19, etc. When you see a number, put it in the appropriate array bucket using integer division, e.g. array[(int)mark/10]++. when you finish the array will contain the count of the number of marks in each bucket.

Comment: I need to use a 2D array to first store the values from the text file, and then look at this array to determine how many marks were less than 40, between 40 and 50, 50 and 60, 60 and 70, and greater than 70. A value of -1 also means that the assignment wasn't handed in.

Answer (score 1):

As food for thought, if this is a school assignment, you might want to apply other things you have learned in the course.

Did you learn sorting yet? Maybe you could sort the list first so that you are not iterating over the array several times. You can just go over it once, grab all the -1's, and spit out how many you have, then grab all the ones in the next bracket and so on.

edit: that is of course, assuming that you are using a 1d array.